# How to use external DataTemplate in Xamarin.Forms using CollectionView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

It try  to move DataTemplate on my CollectionView  to a separate xaml file, for reuse it but not work.

the collectionView on my MainPage:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Spesa.Articoli}" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           <control:ArticoloSpesaControl />
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

and this  is the separate ArticoloSpesaControl.xaml file "ArticoloSpesaControl"

```
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:Class="Prestospesa.View.Control.ArticoloSpesaControl"
      xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.Badge.Abstractions" 
      xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
    >

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0,10,0">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start" Spacing="0">

            <plugin:Badge BadgeText="{Binding Articolo.quantita}" Style="{StaticResource Badge}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BadgeColor}"
                          WidthRequest="35" Margin="0,9,2,0" />

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
            Source="loading.gif"
            WidthRequest="40"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            IsVisible="{Binding RequestPending}"
             />
        <Label Text="{Binding DescrizioneArticolo}" Style="{StaticResource LabelProduct}" 
               WidthRequest="200"
               HeightRequest="40"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"

                />


        <Label Text="{Binding Articolo.prezzoNetto, StringFormat='{0:F}€'}" WidthRequest="90"
               TextColor="Red"
               HeightRequest="50"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Any help is welcome !

Comment: I have found another solution but i still working on it. I share the detail after  i finish.

Comment: OK ,and you can accept it ,which will help more people .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **ContentView** as the `DataTemplate` of the CollectionView

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

          <control:ArticoloSpesaControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

In ArticoloSpesaControl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App3.View1">
  <ContentView.Content>

         //...
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: How is binding shared from the containing control to the ContentView?